# Can I use Point Sprites in Java3D?

Tags: java, 3d, java-3d, point-sprites

It looks like native support for Point Sprites was planned, but never got implemented in Java3D.

[Point Sprite RFE](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVA3D-188)

Short of adding it to the source code and compiling my own version of Java3D, is there any workaround that would let me create a Geometry derived class that uses Point Sprites to render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I came up with, unfortunately, is no.  As of today there seems to be no functionality to allow point sprites and the addition of point sprites has been dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you think about what exactly a point is when rendered, it's really just a small circle.  I'm not super familiar with Java3D, but I'm sure there's either a class that can allow you to render circles, and if not it should be straight-forward to write something that can render a circle.  You'll just have to be careful to ensure that the circle is always facing the camera completely to appear as a point.

Comment: A good try, but sorry, no.  Point sprites are very different from circles.  The whole idea is that you are only sending 1 coordinate to the graphics card vs. 4 of a quad.  Changing it to a circle would actually make the problem even worse.  That's a lot more vertices.  A point sprite is an image or texture that is specified by it's center location, rather than it's 4 corners.  It's more efficient.